# Spring Bean Validation and validating a bean attribute with Regular Expression

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a question about Spring Boot, regular expressions and performing validation on an attribute passed in the body of a REST API call.

I'd like to validate a password field with at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 number and 13 characters.

Other validation is working, but the Regular Expression is not working on the bean.

I've tried the following successfully in an editor.

https://regex101.com/r/lfgL85/1

`^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])`

However, when I set up the pattern on the Java bean with the following annotation, it doesn't seem to work in unit tests. Any thoughts?

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html

```java
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Size(min=13)
    @Pattern(regexp="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])$", message = "Password must contain at least 1 number and uppercase character")
    private String password;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating `password` field with `@NotNull`. It says "`null` elements are considered valid." in the documentation you shared.